# Service to provide data to ListActivity and MapAcitivity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-service, android-mapview

If I have two activities in my app, one with listview and the other with mapview and they both use the same data (the first one shows the list, the other shows pins on a map) should I use IntentService to provide the data to both of them? If so, should I rather use the started service or bound service approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your Activities to a Service, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html.

Create an implementation of the `Binder` interface in your `Service`, e.g.

```
public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}
```

In your Activity, create a new `ServiceConnection` class which will be used to give you access to your Service:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        mMyService = ((MyService.ServiceBinder)service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mMyService = null;
    }
};
```

Here the member variable `mMyService` will give you access to all public members of your Service class.

To create the connection, implement `doBindService` and `doUnbindService` in your Activity:

```
void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

void doUnbindService() {
    // Detach our existing connection.
    unbindService(mConnection);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have one doubt. The documentation says that if nothing is bound to service (with bound service approach) it will stop. And when I switch between my listacivity and mapactivity I think I'll have to unbind it from one and bind to another. Does it mean that the service gets stopped when switching between these activities or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. That's why you use binder. The service works in the background and activities connect to it through binder. Right? And I stop the service with stopSelf() when it finishes its job?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. To keep your service running until explicitly stopped, return `START_STICKY` in your Service's `onStartCommand`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a good solution. Due to a bug it creates memory leaks. Read http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android to find out more. It would be a good answer, but the Binder class should be a standalone one with WeakReference to the Service

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this bug. I have to say I never had any leaking problems with my Binders, but then I always use START_STICKY, so the Service doesn't start and stop alot.

Comment: Now I wonder if I can start AsyncTaskLoader from one activity and connect to it (if it's still running) from another one. It would be the best solution for me. I'll give it a try and comment later.